# SSRS: IIF Statement evaluating incorrectly

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm working in Visual Studio.

In an SSRS Report I have an IIF Statement that is malfunctioning as follows:

There is a field [FieldName] that has a value of 'IHFA' in one of the rows.

I put a field named TestField in the report with this IIF expression in it.

`=iif((Fields!FieldName.Value = "IHFA"), "Y", "N")`

When I run the report, there is an 'N' in TestField in the row that has IHFA in FieldName. There should be a 'Y'.

Another value in the FieldName field [in another row] is 'ServiSolutions'.

If I change the expression in my TestField to:

```
=iif((Fields!FieldName.Value = "ServiSolutions"), "Y", "N")
```

I get a 'Y' in the row that has ServiSolutions in it. So in this case it is working correctly.

I've tried:

LTrim RTrim on the FieldName field in my SQL.

I have returned ASCII values for each of the characters in the field that has the 'IHFA' value [to see if there are hidden characters?] and I get 73  72  70  65 . . . which is correct.

In SSMS, I have tried a Where clause:
    Where FieldName = 'IHFA'
in the SQL and that returns only rows that have 'IHFA' in FieldName.

I'd appreciate any help I can get! :)

Comment: It sounds like it should work and your troubleshooting should have helped but hasn't. Are you sure there isn't a type somewhere? I'm guessing that your field isn't FieldName and you didn't copy and paste the original expression. You can try `=IIF(INSTR(Fields!FieldName.Value = "IHFA") > 0, "Y", "N")` to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Hannover Fist: You guessed correctly - my field is not FieldName. Your expression has an error in it. It should be =IIF(INSTR(Fields!FieldName.Value, "IHFA") > 0, "Y", "N") . . . not . . . = "IHFA". . . right? I tried your suggestion but that didn't work either. It's like SSRS is not reading [some] values in that field correctly ?? I've never run into this problem before [in SSRS, MS Access . . . or in any other environment.

Comment: I decided to go with a workaround because this involved a Production issue. In the SQL for the Report, I added a field with a Case Statement that returns 1 if the value is 'IHFA'. In the report - rather than searching for 'IHFA' in the FieldName field, I am now looking for 1 in the new field. It works fine. Thanks for the suggestion[s]. The original problem is not solved, however, and I'm still interested to know why it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry about the bad syntax. I can't think of what the issue could be either. Do you have any of the Sensitivties **ON** (Case, Width...) in the Dataset Options?

Comment: Everything in the Dataset options is either Default [Collation] or Auto.

Comment: That's what I figured but thought I should mention it just in case. I can't think of what else would be affecting the field. Unless it's actually a **calculated field** that is converting the data from the actual field...

Comment: Have you tried this: `=iif((Fields!FieldName.Value = "%IHFA%"), "Y", "N")` ?

Comment: @Oceans: No - I did not think of trying that at the time. Thanks for the suggestion!